# MongoDB - reduce array of objects by object property value

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to find a way to remove all duplicate documents except the latest one. Here is an example array of objects -

```
[
    {
      id: 123,
      value: "ABC",
      date: "yesterday"
    },
    {
      id: 456,
      value: "DEF",
      date: "today"
    },
    {
      id: 123,
      value: "XYZ",
      date: "today"
    },
]
```

My expected output is -

```
[
    {
      id: 456,
      value: "DEF",
      date: "today"
    },
    {
      id: 123,
      value: "XYZ",
      date: "today"
    },
]
```

The way I am thinking to solve the issue -

```
db.collectionName.aggregate([
{
  $sort: { date: -1 }
},
{
$reduce: {
  input: "CURRENT_ARRAY",
  initialValue: [],
  in: {
    $cond: [
      { "CONDITION_TO_CHECK_id_MATCHED" }
    ]
  }
}
])
```

But I can't design the code it should be implemented.

Comment: Are `date`s actually text, or BSON `Dates`s?  So, you want to keep the most recent (using BSON dates) or the last if text?  Is `CURRENT_ARRAY` the field name of an array within each document, or is that just symbolic and each object shown in your example are individual documents within the `collectionName` collection?

Comment: `date` is BSON `Date`. `CURRENT_ARRAY` is not an array field name but represents the documents of the collection.

Answer (score 2):

You need to `$group` by `id` and take the "last" document, here is a quick example:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$id",
      last: {
        $last: "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: "$last"
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/DtUxHkLyxLy)

The issue with this approach is that we're relying on the "natural" order to match with the latest date, this is probably true for you're app but if it's not you'll need to either add a `$sort` stage prior to the group stage on some field that can ensure correct order ( the "date" field is a good candidate if it actually contains a date ). If your using Mongo version 5.2+ you can use the [bottom](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/bottom/) operator instead of the sort stage.